# SAS- How to split a large dataset by certain requirements?

Tags: split, sas

```
data AXPM061204200; 
set a; 
call execute ("data work.data_"||strip(put(_ric,$13.))||"_"||strip(put(date,yymmddn8.))||"; 
               set work.a;if date="||date||" and _ric="||input(_ric,$13.)||";run;"); 
run;
```

I have a large dataset that contians multiple date (from 20120103 to 20121205) and contracts (_ric= AXPM061204200.c, AXPC061204200.c and so on).

I tried to use "call exectue" to split the dataset and here is my code. It can only split by date, but fail in contract name (_ric). The error was : Variable AXPM061203800 is uninitialized. How could I solve this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is ok after DomPazz correction, but it isn't well optimized.

You read your source data a lot of times, but it is possible to read this data set only two times.

Check it out this solution and compare a performance both of codes.

```
%macro split;
proc sql;
    create table tmp as
    select distinct date, _ric
    from work.a;

    select count(*)
    into :obs
    from work.tmp;

    %let obs=&obs.;

    select date, _ric, catx("_", "work.data", substr(_ric, 1, 13), put(date, yymmddn8.))
    into :date1-:date&obs., :ric1-:ric&obs., :setname1-:setname&obs.
    from work.tmp;
quit;

data 
%do i = 1 %to &obs.;
    &&setname&i
%end;
;
    set work.a;
select;
%do i = 1 %to &obs.;
    when(_ric = "&&ric&i" and date = &&date&i) output &&setname&i;
%end;
end;
%mend split;

%split
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm not good at macro, so I usually attempt to avoid using macro. But, I'll try your way that seems more efficient!

Comment: Hi, your code may have some error. SAS reported error as "

Comment: Hi, your code may have some error. SAS reported error as "NOTE: The SAS System stopped processing this step because of errors.
WARNING: The data set WORK.DATA_AXPA061203500_20120103 may be incomplete.  When this step was stopped there were 0 observations
         and 106 variables.
WARNING: Data set WORK.DATA_AXPA061203500_20120103 was not replaced because this step was stopped.

Comment: I can't say, because you pasted only some Warnings and Notes. The error should be there also.

Comment: I find the error code: ERROR: Unsatisfied WHEN clause and no OTHERWISE clause at line 271 column 2.
I tried to put [otherwise] into the macro, but it still didn't work.

Comment: I solved the problem. It raised by the format of "date". I transferred it from date format to numeric format.  Many Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is in here:

```
" and _ric="||input(_ric,$13.)||"
```

That will resolve to

```
if ... and _ric=AXPC061204200.c
```

SAS thinks that `AXPC061204200.c` is a variable and is complaining that it doesn't know what it is.

Change to (notice the extra `'` I added)

```
" and _ric='"||input(_ric,$13.)||"'
```

You will send SAS

```
if ... and _ric=`AXPC061204200.c`
```

Comment: Many thanks!!!!! It works!! And I have another small question. If _ric is a numeric variable (like 123), how could I adopt this numeric variable in this situation? If I can use date to tell SAS that is a date variable, does it have a "code" to tell SAS this is a numerical variable?

Comment: remove the `'`, then use the `put(_ric,best.)` function to write your numeric variable value.  You can change the format as you need.  `put(var,format)` converts a numeric variable to text using the specified format.